# Permissions reset?

Tags: active-directory, permissions, windows-server-2012-r2

I am a developer and I have a Windows Server 2012 development environment. Nothing special, onlyAD and a WebServer are installed on it. Everything is configured with the default values. When I do the following:

```
Active Diretory Users and Computers > View > Advanced Features
```

And then

```
right click on a User or Container > Security > set some security
```

For example, give the user `DevelopmentUser1` `Full Permission` on User `Adam` everything works fine. But after some hours or after a restart, the permissions are gone, somehow they are reset.

What happened here? Why does this happen and how can I make it persistent?

**Result for dcdiag /q:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>dcdiag /q
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x00002720
            Time Generated: 04/28/2016   06:11:16
            Event String:
            The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Acti
vation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
         An error event occurred.  EventID: 0x00002720
            Time Generated: 04/28/2016   06:11:16
            Event String:
            The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Acti
vation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID
         ......................... SP2013 failed test SystemLog

C:\Users\Administrator>
```

Comment: Please run 'dcdiag /q' and add the result to your question. What you're experiencing is not normal.

Comment: *Please us proper formatting...* Anyway, that does not look like it's causing your issues. No expert, but what you describe sounds like a USN rollback. Problem is that your DC is a development machine, so figuring out what went wrong at what time that causes regular USN rollbacks is cumbersome. You could start by reading [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/875495) and see if something applies to your environment.

Comment: @Daniel: Thanks a lot. It really seems that only the permission for the `Administrator` is getting reset. The article helped. The other accounts are not getting reset. Write this as an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No expert, but what you describe sounds like a USN rollback. Problem is that your DC is a development machine, so figuring out what went wrong at what time that causes regular USN rollbacks is cumbersome. You could start by reading [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/875495) and see if something applies to your environment and then take action from there.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely running to issues with the [AdminSDHolder](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.09.sdadminholder.aspx) process.

> Each Active Directory domain has an object called AdminSDHolder, which resides in the System container of the domain. The AdminSDHolder object has a unique Access Control List (ACL), which is used to control the permissions of security principals that are members of built-in privileged Active Directory groups (what I like to call "protected" groups). Every hour, a background process runs on the domain controller that holds the PDC Emulator operations master role. It compares the ACL on all security principals (users, groups and computer accounts) that belong to protected groups against the ACL on the AdminSDHolder object. If the size or the binary string is different, the security descriptor on the object is overwritten by the security descriptor from the AdminSDHolder object.

The objects that are getting reset are likely in one of the "protected" groups.